# Use list values as dictionary keys as key val

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am creating a dictionary using a list value as a key. Now I want to get dictionary keys in same order as list values. Please find the code below:

```
dict = {}

category_list = [u'Customer', u'Consumers', u'OpenERP Partners', u'Basic Partner', u'Retailers', u'Supplier']

for category in category_list:
    dict[category] = 0.0

print "dict--->", dict
```

I am getting a output as:

```
dict--->{u'Customer': 0.0, u'Consumers': 0.0, u'Basic Partner': 0.0, u'Supplier': 0.0, u'Retailers': 0.0, u'OpenERP Partners': 0.0}
```

But I want dictionary keys in the same order as list is defined. i.e. output should be like:

```
 dict--->{u'Customer': 0.0, u'Consumers': 0.0, u'OpenERP Partners': 0.0, u'Basic Partner': 0.0,  u'Retailers': 0.0, u'Supplier': 0.0,}
```

Comment: Sigh. Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sigh? Is that necessary? People come here for help, not denigration. You could also vote the Q down; a better message than snark.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). For example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> category_list = [u'Customer', u'Consumers', u'OpenERP Partners', u'Basic Partner', u'Retailers', u'Supplier']
>>> for category in category_list:
...   d[category] = 0.0
... 
>>> print d
OrderedDict([(u'Customer', 0.0), (u'Consumers', 0.0), (u'OpenERP Partners', 0.0), (u'Basic Partner', 0.0), (u'Retailers', 0.0), (u'Supplier', 0.0)])
```

Also, `dict` is already used in python to refer to the dict class, so you should avoid using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just use your original list to print the dictionary in the right order, although I'm not sure what you're planning to do with the dictionary eventuallly.

```
for categ in category_list:
     print categ, dict[categ]
```